# Php: turning it into a recursive function

Tags: php, function, design-patterns

I have currently two classes.

the `ArrayCompare` class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Tools\RegexExtract;

class ArrayCompare
{


    public function compare(Array $arrayToCompare)
    {

        $elementData = new ElementMetaData();
        $metaData = $elementData->extract($arrayToCompare[0], [], $initial=true);

        foreach ($arrayToCompare as $currentElement) {

            $metaData = $elementData->extract($currentElement, $metaData);

        }

        return $metaData;

    }

}
```

which uses the `ElementMetaData` class

```
    <?php
/**
 * A class for extracting meta data from an element.
*/

namespace App\Tools\RegexExtract;

class ElementMetaData
{

    public function extract($element, $metaDataToCompare = [], $initial = false)
    {

        if ($initial == true) {
            $this->isInteger($element) ? $returnMetaData['isInteger'] = $this->isInteger($element) : null;
            $returnMetaData['length'] = $this->length($element);
        }

        else {

            $returnMetaData=$metaDataToCompare;


        if ($returnMetaData != []) {
            if (isset ($returnMetaData['isInteger']) && !$this->isInteger($element)) {
                unset($returnMetaData['isInteger']);

            }
            if (isset ($returnMetaData['length']) && $this->length($element) != $returnMetaData['length']) {
                unset($returnMetaData['length']);

            }

        }
        }

        return $returnMetaData;


    }

    private function isInteger($element)
    {
        return is_int($element);
    }

private function length($element)
{
    return strlen($element);

}

}
```

the basic functionality is:

given I have an array

```
$arr=[1,2,3];
```

I want to get the "similarities" between **ALL** Elements. According to a an array i Predefine...so this would deliver this result:

```
$metaArray=['isInteger'=>true,'length'=>1];
```

and this would deliver just length as similarity:

```
$arr=[1,2,'D'];
$metaArray=['length'=>1];
```

While this array would deliver an empty result `[]`

```
$arr=[1,2,'3D']; // result is [] since not all integers or not all of same length.
```

Now my solution does not use recursive functions...but I am sure it can be used somehow.

Also, I want to add more "criteria"....So `"isEmailAdress", "beginswithA"`....etc....and this would make my if statements a horror....so what is the best strategy/design pattern to follow here?

Comment: I cannot see any recursive patterns in your task. Though of course you could write any sequence folding as a recursion. The question: do you need this here?

Comment: Good to hear that. I thought there is room for emprovement/performance . Since those arrays can be long....But In case there are better ways for readability, code management on the design patterns path, would be glad to hear it.

Comment: I don't see any need for separate `ElementMetaData` class, because it has no state at all and serves just to call `extract` in static manner. It should not be a class, the whole thing may be implemented just in a single function, using `if..elseif` or `case` to test your criteria. Especially if performance is a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any need for recursion here, so I'll just make a suggestion for a design approach:

Implement each criterion as a class:

```
abstract class Criterion {

    protected $valid = true;

    abstract public function initialize($value);
    abstract public function check($value);

    public function isValid() {
        return $this->valid;
    }

}

class Length extends Criterion {

    protected $length;

    public function initialize($value) {
        $this->length = strlen($value);
    }

    public function check($value) {
        if ($this->length != strlen($value)) {
            $this->valid = false;
        }
    }

}
```

You then make an array of all your criteria:

```
$criteria = [new Length, ...];
foreach ($criteria as $criterion) {
    $criterion->initialize($values[0]);
}
```

And slowly whittle them down through your values:

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
    foreach ($criteria as $criterion) {
        $criterion->check($value);
    }
}

$commonCriteria = array_filter($criteria, function (Criterion $criterion) {
    return $criterion->isValid();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

@deceze beat me to it by fair margin... but I'll still post my solution that works basically with the same principles.

```
abstract class abstractComparer
{
    private $array;
    private $result = true;
    protected $name;

    public function compareArray($array)
    {
        $current = null;

        foreach ($array as $index => $value)
        {
            $this->result = $this->result && $this->compareValues($index, $current, $value);
            $current = $value;
        }
    }

    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->result;
    }    

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public abstract function compareValues($index, $value1, $value2);

    public abstract function getSuccessValue();
}

class intComparer extends abstractComparer
{
    protected $name = "isInteger";

    public function compareValues($index, $value1, $value2)
    {
        return is_int($value2);
    }

    public function getSuccessValue()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class lengthComparer extends abstractComparer
{
    protected $name   = "length";
    protected $length = 0;

    public function compareValues($index, $value1, $value2)
    {
        $this->length = strlen($value2);
        return $index == 0 || strlen($value1) == $this->length;
    }

    public function getSuccessValue()
    {
        return $this->length;
    }
}
```

And do the actual processing like this:

```
$temp = [1,2,3];

$comparers = [new intComparer(), new lengthComparer()];
$result = array();

foreach ($comparers as $comparer)
{
    $comparer->compareArray($temp);

    if ($comparer->getResult())
    {
        $result[$comparer->getName()] = $comparer->getSuccessValue();
    }
}

//var_dump($result);
```